# Adding a keybinding to enter vi copy mode in tmux

Tags: tmux

Pressing `C-b and [` puts tmux in copy mode, this lets you select and copy text in a manner similar to vi.

Could you please show me how to add a new key binding like `C-j` to do this?

I guess it would look like - `bind -n C-j function-to-enter-copy-mode`

But, I don't know what the function to enter vi copy mode is called. I think I just need the function name.

Answer (score 0):

`bind -n C-j copy-mode`

Add this to the tmux configuration file and reload tmux config